# Json Data Transfer from server to Client

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

We have implemented a Listing Page which has features like Pagination,Search and Filters. All the Features are implemented on Client Side (Jquery) so we were sending the Complete Required Details as Json from server (c#) to Client Side. Now Records are increased drastically and hence Json data transfer from server to client is taking long time.

I tried following methods

- Content-Encoding ="Chunked" and Content-Encoding="gzip"
- Transformed Json Array to small parts and used Signal R to push the Json Details to Client Side and
  concating Multiple json parts to Single Json object in Client Side.
  In both the above methods Data transfer time was not reduced.

How can we transfer huge Json data from server to client side?

Comment: jquery data table is better http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/11/implement-jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have a issue with transferring the json from server to client. If Json is more than 10mb then download time increases expenonentialy with data size. Do you have suggestions on sending data chunks asynchronously to client side.

Comment: I have also same issue